# Lispy and Racket

Tags: parentheses, delimiters

I'm using lispy with Racket and having a tough time with some forms.  Namely, if I with to a `let` or keyword argument I can't seem to type the inner `[` character. For example, I want to define a function:

```
(define (my-func arg1 #:keyword-arg2 [arg2 arg2]))
```

So everything works fine until I get to the `[`.  As soon as I press that key, the pointer moves back to the previous set of parentheses.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `C-h k [` tell you?

Comment: Please provide a step-by-step recipe, starting with `emacs -Q`. State what major mode and minor modes are current. If you don't start from `emacs -Q` then it will help to provide more contextual info - what libraries you've loaded etc.

Comment: This is standard `lispy` behaviour: hit `}` to insert a pair of square brackets.  Check the [documentation](http://oremacs.com/lispy/#lispy-forward) for this and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type C-q [ to insert a single square bracket. As noted in the comments type } for a balanced pair of square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

As noted this is the keybindindgdefined by lispy - } is bound to lispy-brackets which inserts the pair []

I liked the idea of modes that lispy uses but found the keys too odd - I don't like or try to remember vi:)

I found the package [lispy-mnemonic](https://github.com/itsjeyd/lispy-mnemonic) useful as it rebinds keys to something that I found easier to remember. However I quickly found issues there and edited that mode heavily.

I have kept the line for [ so using this mode will solve that issue

```
(define-key lispy-mnemonic-mode-map (kbd "[") 'lispy-brackets)
```

So my recommendation is copy lispy-mnemonic and edit it to match your needs.

As note in lispy-mnemonics README

> Target Audience

> If you:
> would like to start learning Lispy
> have played around with Lispy but not mastered it
> haven't burned Vim-style key bindings into your muscle memory
> find that mnemonics make it easier to learn and remember new commands and key bindings
> ... there is a good chance you'll benefit from using lispy-mnemonic.